# when selected options of a multiselect add another fields using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can i create another fields in form every time  select a new option, and each name of this fields change with values of options, i tried and all i get is the length and values of multi select

```
<select class="form-control select2 quality" multiple="multiple" name="quality[]" data-placeholder="Select a Quality" style="width: 100%;">
    @foreach($quality as $quali)
        <option value="{{$quali->id}}">{{$quali->quality_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Did you try anything with JQuery yet? simply write a method in Jquery with event type change. see https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: yes i tried but i dont know how to change the name of every field created

Comment: oh got you, i will post something for you after some time

Comment: How many fields do you want? Post your jQuery code, it will be of some help.

Comment: 3 fields for each option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the *each name of this fields change with values of options* part. But actually here, I try to listen to `change` event provided by select2. Then find the selected value using `:selected` pseudo selector by jQuery to find which selected options' value and text.

Hope you get some ideas!

```js
$(function () {
  // Apply select2
  $('.select2').select2()
  
  // Just a small helper
  var _h = {
    capitalize: function (str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
    },
    render: function (id, name) {
      var html = ''
      
      $.each([1, 2, 3], function (k, v) {
        html += '<input type="text" name="quality[' + name + '][' + id + '][' + v + ']" placeholder="' + _h.capitalize(name) + '-' + v + '" class="block">'
    })
      
      return html
    }
  }
  
  // Now listed to change event of select2
  $(document).on('change', '.quality', function () {
    $('#append').html('') // truncate any appended nodes
    
    $(this).find(':selected').each(function (k, v) {
      $('#append').append(_h.render($(this).val(), $(this).text()))
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<style>
.block {
  display: block;
  margin: .5rem 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<select class="form-control select2 quality" multiple="multiple" name="quality[]" data-placeholder="Select a Quality" style="width: 100%;">
  <option value="1">Standard</option>
  <option value="2">Outstanding</option>
  <option value="3">Whatever</option>
</select>

<div id="append"></div>
```

Comment: Well, based on my example case, you have to create another function which returns string dom/the template just like the `render` function.